# Effect of pump suction lift on pump vibrations and motor current

Tags: fluid-mechanics, motors, pressure, pumps, hydraulics

Consider the case of an electric motor driving a centrifugal pump.

The pump is installed above the tank.

In Case-I, the tank is completely filled with water.

In Case-II, the tank is emptied and thus the water level has decreased.

This scenario has been shown in below figure:

Note: Delivery_head_1 = Delivery_head_2

[image]

Now, I have below two questions:

**Question-1: In which situation the motor current will be high?**

According to me, Total_head_2 > Total_head_1.

Hence, the hydraulic power (P) demand is more in Case-II since P depends on Head (H) as such:

[image]

Since hydraulic power demand has increased, the electric power consumption of the motor has increased, and thus the motor current increases in Case-II.

However, the contradiction is, the pump characteristic curve tells us that, as head increases, the hydraulic power demand decreases as shown in below figure:

[image]

So, what could be the correct logic here for the motor current to increase in Case-II?

**Question-2: In which situation the pump vibration will be high?**

According to me, in Case-II, the NPSHA decreases since Suction_lift_2 is more.

As a result, the pressure head [Static+Dynamic] at point-2 in the suction side is less for Case-II.

Since pressure is less, the force of impact of water on pump impeller is less and thus the vibration is less in Case-II.

My thought process could be wrong.

Can somebody please let me know any possible suggestion on my above two queries.